# ssh login without welcome banner

Tags: bash, ssh

I am using ssh from a program which sends commands to ssh and parses answers. However, each time I log in, I get the welcome banner like:

```
Linux mymachine 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
...
```

I do not want this banner, because my parser would need to deal with it. Is it possible to login with ssh and not to get this banner at the beginning?

Comment: It is possible that the remote admin has set up things so that the banner is always printed no matter what. If simple things like `.hushlogin` don't work, look into how `sshd` is configured on the remote host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will run command1 command2 and command3 on the remote_host.

```
ssh user@remote_host 'command1; command2; command3'
```

No banners are displayed.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `ssh my_remote_host bash` is doing exactly what I need.

Comment: This is a way that you can run commands remotely over ssh connection...You can also run command remotely in other way over bash script then banner are removed as well..

Comment: @MortezaLSC `#!/bin/bash ; user=johndoe ; host=remote_hoste ; ssh $user@$host 'w; uptime; free ' >remote_host.info` This mini script is run locally; sends commands to the remote host; their out put is stored locally; and no banners are displayed. Just put the rest of the code after the hashbang on separate lines.

Comment: I'm adding what I am saying :)

Comment: @Keith Reynolds I UPDATED my answer

Comment: Thanks for all answers. What I actually needed was an interactive session where I could send shell commands one after another and parse answers on the fly. I just wanted to remove the initial banner.

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to silence this banner, and other diagnostic messages, by passing `-q` to SSH:

```
ssh -q user@remote_host
```

If you want to make `-q` permanent for all your SSH sessions, do:

```
echo "LogLevel QUIET" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it precisely says what needs to be done.

Comment: This does not work for me (ssh -q into multipass ubuntu guest vm). Adding .hushlogin worked.

Comment: Definitely worked for me. @kol Maybe the result depends on the the SSH version.

Answer (score 11):

What works here seems to depend on the operating system, SSH version, and the server-side configuration of `sshd`.

For connecting to a stock Ubuntu 18 server `ssh -q` didn't work for me, and neither did `ssh -o LogLevel=error` that is suggested elsewhere.

What did work is the comment posted under the question about creating a `.hushlogin` file in the remote user's home directory:

```
$ ssh myuser@myhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-55-generic x86_64)
<snip>
Last login: Thu Aug  1 14:04:26 2019 from 1.2.3.4
myuser@myhost$ touch .hushlogin
myuser@myhost$ exit
```

Then:

```
$ ssh myuser@myhost echo 'Test'
Test
```

Answer (score 4):

Try ssh -q to supress the banner message

Answer (score 1):

If you expect more than 1000 lines in the server answer then replace 1000 with a corresponding number **or the server answer will be truncated**.

```
# Demo script file creation \
DIVIDER="___"; echo "echo $DIVIDER; echo 100; echo 200; echo 300;" > "./test.sh"; \
# \    
# Getting the answer without the banner \
ssh -q login@server.name < "./test.sh" | grep -A1000 -e "^$DIVIDER" | tail -n +2
```

Success

```
100
200
300
```

The same command without

```
| grep -A1000 -e "^$DIVIDER" | tail -n +2
```

gives

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux...
[...]
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
___
100
200
300
```

You can replace "___" (three underscores) with any exotic sign(s) or even password (which can't be found in the beginnings of lines of the banner).

To avoid the replacing 1000 with a corresponding number (and possible truncation of big server answers) search something about "how to grep all lines after match" and modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

For running commands remotely:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT='
#Your commands
'
sshpass -p<pass> ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p <port> user@host "$SCRIPT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question with the solution based on Keith Reynolds answer. I am using:

```
ssh my_host bash
```

allowing bash interaction without banner and without prompt.